# OPC server is always NULL

Tags: server, opc

when I use `CoCreateInstanceEx` I always get NULL as a result.
My code is like that:

```
bool Connect(Str a_sServerName, COSERVERINFO* CoServerInfo)
{
    CLSID CLSID_OPCServer;
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = CLSIDFromString(a_sServerName, &CLSID_OPCServer);

    if( hr == S_FALSE )
    {
        // Log string "Wrong CLSID of OPC server"
        return false;
    }

    LONG cmq = 1; // nbr of class instance to create.
    MULTI_QI queue[] = { { &IID_IOPCServer, nullptr, 0 } };

    // HERE IS SOMETHING WRONG WITH THE queue VARIABLE
    hr = CoCreateInstanceEx(CLSID_OPCServer, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, CoServerInfo, cmq, queue);

    if( hr == S_FALSE )
    {
        // Log string "Error creating OPC server instance"
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        // Log string "Successful connection to the OPC server"
    }

    pIOPCServer = (IOPCServer*) queue[0].pItf;
    //AND HERE pIOPCServer IS NULL
}
```

I get no errors, everything seem to work properly. But unfortunately the `pIOPCServer` is NULL.
Don't you suspect what could be wrong here?

For any help great thanks in advance.
Best Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You need to check not just the HRESULT from CoCreateInstanceEx, but also the HRESULT in queue[0].hr. The reason of the problem will most likely be there.

Comment: Hmm. Great thank's. That's true. There is `queue[0].hr == E_INVALIDARG`. But I still have no idea why? I inherited the code from an employee who is no longer in contact and I have no idea how to go about it.

Comment: As I know the code was working before. So I wonder if I have some old libraries on my computer.

Comment: How is CoServerInfo filled in?

Comment: The `CoServerInfo` is filled like:
`DWORD dwReserved1;` and it is equal `0`
`LPWSTR pwszName;` - it looks like some string filled with IP address
`DWORD dwReserved2;` - it is also equal `0`
And finally there is `COAUTHINFO *pAuthInfo;` which is filled like that:
`DWORD dwAuthnSvc;` equal `4294967295`
`DWORD dwAuthzSvc;` equal `0`
`LPWSTR pwszServerPrincName;` equal `NULL`
`DWORD dwAuthnLevel;` equal `0`
`DWORD dwImpersonationLevel;` equal `3`
`DWORD dwCapabilities;` equal `0`
And `COAUTHIDENTITY *pAuthIdentityData;` this is some login data like user ID, password length etc.

Comment: Sorry for such ugly comment but not sure how to format comments.

Comment: But as I've read in documentation the `pServerInfo` could be `NULL`. So I tried that, but now the `hr == REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` which means something like "class is not registered`. And `queue[0].hr` is still equal to `NULL`

Comment: If the OPC server is supposed to be on the remote machine, then the computer name or IP address (where the remote OPC server resides) goes to COSERVERINFO.pwszName. So when you set COSERVERINFO to NULL, the function then looks for the OPC server on the local computer instead, and if it not there, which is probably expected, you get REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG. But this tells us that the E_INVALIDARG really means that there is something wrong inside the COSERVERINFO. But I do not know what. Try experimenting with it (for start, set the COAUTHIDENTITY to NULL).

Comment: Hello, thanks. Yes I’ve already tried to set COAUTHIDENTITY to NULL. And suddenly the problem disappeared. But the case is I need to make it work remotely. I wonder maybe on the remote machine there are some wrong setting. But more probably I use wrong pwszName. I use straight public IP in format like that „XX.XXX.XXX.XXX”.

Comment: Hmm... Now I see that pwszName is not part of COAUTHIDENTITY, it is also not part of COAUTHINFO. Sorry i made some mess. I need to make more tests. Thanks.